# How to test a controller with model injection but without middleware?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

When I test this:

```
use WithoutMiddleware;

public function testPutSportOK()
{
    $sport = Sport::first();

    $sportName = 'Modification '.$sport->sport_name;
    $position = random_int(0,100);

    $post = [
        'sport_name' => $sportName,
        'position' => $position
    ];

    $response = $this->json('PUT', '/api/sports/'.$sport->id, $post);

    $response->assertStatus(200);
```

The test failed because I use the model injection in my controller. I understand that this injection needs the "bindings" middleware. But as I disabled all the middlewares, this injection cannot be done.

I disabled the middlewares for authentication reasons.

I tried to add this:

```
$this->withMiddleware('bindings');
```

But it's still the same.

How to test a controller using the model injection and without middlewares?

### Edit

Add the controller with the model injection:

```
public function update(Request $request, Sport $sport)
{
    // var_dump($sport);

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'sport_name' => 'required',
        'position' => 'required|int'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
    }

    try {
        // not necessary with the injection model
        // $sport = Sport::findOrFail($id);
        $sport->fill($request->all());
        $sport->save();

        return new SportResource($sport);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response()->json($ex->getMessage(), 400);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the injected model? Can you show your complete code?

Comment: I added the source of the controller in which you can see the injection of the model. thanks

Comment: Why do you disable all the middlewares? testing work great with them

Comment: I disable the middleware because my routes are protected by a token "Bearer". And for my tests I do not need it. But perhaps it is not a good practice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source code [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/45ce5ff53d7a3fe1d189612288dc087ef1bb28de/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php#L93), you can actually disable "some" of your middlewares (instead of disabling them all) by giving an array of middlewares you **WANT** to disable.

```
$this->withoutMiddleware([
    \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate,
    \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated,
    // Add more here
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I gave up the idea of ​​model injection. To prefer the passage of a classic id between the route and the controller.

As this my PHPUnit + Postman tests work perfectly and I'm not bored with this "binding" middleware any more.

Certainly it requires to write one more line in the controller to read the corresponding model in database. But it's only one line. I accept it !

Comment: having same issue, did you find out something/